# Bootstrap Layout Navbar and Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3 for a layout and have added a dropdown to the navbar but when I add btn-primary the text is black so cannot be seen, if I remove the btn-primary then the corner radius seems to overlap the menu.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="Javascript:void(0);">Title Information </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown btn-primary">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle btn-primary" href="Javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Close</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  </nav>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="col-md-12 column">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

some images:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuirgtcfc0obl04/Image1.JPG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/en0vooc1z99hbkh/Image2.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Take out the "btn-primary" but change it to "btn" only, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the style of bootstrap button.

I just added this to change the color of text :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Link Demo : http://www.bootply.com/Ukp9KCUuFP

You can also give an "unique id" then customize the style for this button.

```
<a id="test" class="dropdown-toggle btn-primary" href="Javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
```

**css:**

```
#test {

  color:white;

}

#test:hover{
  color:black;
}
```

Link : http://www.bootply.com/XWF4x6uhmz

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `btn-primary` classes, as these aren't required.

You also have `</div>` and `</nav>` closing in the wrong order, and two extra `</div>` at the bottom of your code.

With the `btn-primary` removed, and the above fixed, then you get the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jym0k8r/